# How to add trailing "/" to website with .htaccess

Tags: html

Hi i'm trying to add a trailing "/" to my website for the past few weeks and every code and website tutorial to edit the .htaccess i've tried has failed to work. All my webpages end with ".html". The first part of my htaccess code forces the use of "https" and "www". What I want is that + when a user clicks on a link on my site to say "a href="help.html" it will load help.html but it will appear in the address bar as "https://www.example.com/help/" I don't care if I need to change all my links to omit the ".html" or if I need to change all my filenames to omit the ".html" extension. I just want that trailing "/" + my www and https force. Here is my code so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]

Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

P.S. I am aware of the 302 redirect as i'm testing, once my code is working i'll change to 301. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After more digging from websites that use this technique, I think i've figured out the structure, please correct me if i'm wrong. To use a trailing slash the .html file needs to be renamed index.html and be under a subfolder with the name you want in front of the trailing slash. For example I want www.example.com/blog.html to read www.example.com/blog/. For this I need to rename blog .html to index.html and place it in a folder entitled "blog" then instead of linking to www.example.com/blog/index.html I would link to www.example.com/blog/ and the index.html will show.

Answer (score 0):

Add this and If the URL doesnt have a trailing slash the htaccess will redirect the browser to the URL with a the slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added your suggested code to my .htaccess file. It has no effect on links ending in .html. It does however add a "/" to links given no extension in the a href which is good. The problem is the link won't load the page with a .html or with no extension at all, in both cases I get 404 not found. I can't rename the file with a trailing slash as that's an invalid filename. For this code to work how do i make the link and what do I name the file?